# Generating Image & Serving via HTTP with Go

Tags: formatting, go, type-safety

### What is does

I'm reading [The Go Programming Language](https://www.gopl.io/). Below is my code for the [last exercise](https://www.gopl.io/ch1.pdf#page=42) in the first chapter, which is to create a webserver, generate an image, and serve the image via the server, allowing modifications of the image via query string parameters, eg: `localhost:8000/?cycles=25&bgcolor=0,255,255`.

### My Concerns

I'm open to any and all suggestions, but any advice specifically concerning these points would be especially helpful.

**Duplicated code**. There's just enough duplication to trigger my OCD, but each one is slightly different so I'm not sure how I could delegate to a function without creating a bunch of very similar functions. In particular, the two `for` loops where I'm parsing colors really bother me.

**Type Juggling**. [`strconv.ParseInt`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt) has a third argument to specify the bit size but always returns `int64` anyway, so I still have to explicitly cast then to unsigned 8 bit integers. Take a look at my `img.SetColorIndex` call where I'm doing all sorts of casting just for some simple arithmetic.

**Concision**. I am baffled at the fact that I can write a simple server using the standard library with about 4 lines of code, but turning a string into an array of numbers took me 19 lines of code. And I had to use basically the same 19 lines twice because I couldn't figure out what to specify as the type when passing a [`color.RGBA`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#RGBA) as a function parameter.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "io"

    "image"
    "image/color"
    "image/gif"
    "math"
    "math/rand"

    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

var bgcolor = color.RGBA{0, 0, 0, 255}
var fgcolor = color.RGBA{255, 255, 255, 255}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", serveImage)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8000", nil))
}

func serveImage(w http.ResponseWriter, r* http.Request) {
    if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }
    cycles := 10.0
    res := 0.001
    size := 100
    frames := 64
    delay := 8
    if value, exists := r.Form["cycles"]; exists {
        if v, err := strconv.ParseFloat(value[0], 64); err == nil {
            cycles = v
        }
    }
    if value, exists := r.Form["res"]; exists {
        if v, err := strconv.ParseFloat(value[0], 64); err == nil {
            res = v
        }
    }
    if value, exists := r.Form["size"]; exists {
        if v, err := strconv.ParseFloat(value[0], 64); err == nil {
            size = int((v-1)/2)
        }
    }
    if value, exists := r.Form["frames"]; exists {
        if v, err := strconv.ParseInt(value[0], 10, 0); err == nil {
            frames = int(v)
        }
    }
    if value, exists := r.Form["delay"]; exists {
        if v, err := strconv.ParseInt(value[0], 10, 0); err == nil {
            delay = int(v)
        }
    }
    if value, exists := r.Form["bgcolor"]; exists {
        BGColorLoop: 
            for {
                parts := strings.Split(value[0], ",")
                if len(parts) != 3 {
                    break BGColorLoop
                }
                for _, val := range parts {
                    if v, err := strconv.ParseInt(val, 10, 0); err != nil || int(v) > 255 || int(v) < 0 {
                        break BGColorLoop
                    }
                }
                r, _ := strconv.ParseInt(parts[0], 10, 8)
                g, _ := strconv.ParseInt(parts[1], 10, 8)
                b, _ := strconv.ParseInt(parts[2], 10, 8)
                bgcolor = color.RGBA{uint8(r), uint8(g), uint8(b), 255}
                break BGColorLoop
            }
    }
    if value, exists := r.Form["fgcolor"]; exists {
        FGColorLoop: 
            for {
                parts := strings.Split(value[0], ",")
                if len(parts) != 3 {
                    break FGColorLoop
                }
                for _, val := range parts {
                    if v, err := strconv.ParseInt(val, 10, 0); err != nil || int(v) > 255 || int(v) < 0 {
                        break FGColorLoop
                    }
                }
                r, _ := strconv.ParseInt(parts[0], 10, 8)
                g, _ := strconv.ParseInt(parts[1], 10, 8)
                b, _ := strconv.ParseInt(parts[2], 10, 8)
                fgcolor = color.RGBA{uint8(r), uint8(g), uint8(b), 255}
                break FGColorLoop
            }
    }
    lissajous(w, cycles, res, size, frames, delay)
}

func lissajous(out io.Writer, cycles float64, res float64, size int, nframes int, delay int) {
    freq := rand.Float64() * 3.0 
    anim := gif.GIF{LoopCount: nframes}
    phase := 0.0 
    palette := []color.Color{bgcolor, fgcolor}
    for i := 0; i<nframes; i++ {
        rect := image.Rect(0, 0, 2*size+1, 2*size+1)
        img := image.NewPaletted(rect, palette)
        for t:=0.0; t<cycles*2*math.Pi; t+=res {
            x := math.Sin(t)
            y := math.Sin(t*freq+phase)
            img.SetColorIndex(size+int(x*float64(size)+0.5), size+int(y*float64(size)+0.5), 1)
        }
        phase += 0.1
        anim.Delay = append(anim.Delay, delay)
        anim.Image = append(anim.Image, img)
    }
    gif.EncodeAll(out, &anim)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code must be correct. To be sure that code is correct, code must be readable.

---

I took some of your baffling code:

```
var bgcolor = color.RGBA{0, 0, 0, 255}
var fgcolor = color.RGBA{255, 255, 255, 255}

if value, exists := r.Form["bgcolor"]; exists {
BGColorLoop:
    for {
        parts := strings.Split(value[0], ",")
        if len(parts) != 3 {
            break BGColorLoop
        }
        for _, val := range parts {
            if v, err := strconv.ParseInt(val, 10, 0); err != nil || int(v) > 255 || int(v) < 0 {
                break BGColorLoop
            }
        }
        r, _ := strconv.ParseInt(parts[0], 10, 8)
        g, _ := strconv.ParseInt(parts[1], 10, 8)
        b, _ := strconv.ParseInt(parts[2], 10, 8)
        bgcolor = color.RGBA{uint8(r), uint8(g), uint8(b), 255}
        break BGColorLoop
    }
}
if value, exists := r.Form["fgcolor"]; exists {
FGColorLoop:
    for {
        parts := strings.Split(value[0], ",")
        if len(parts) != 3 {
            break FGColorLoop
        }
        for _, val := range parts {
            if v, err := strconv.ParseInt(val, 10, 0); err != nil || int(v) > 255 || int(v) < 0 {
                break FGColorLoop
            }
        }
        r, _ := strconv.ParseInt(parts[0], 10, 8)
        g, _ := strconv.ParseInt(parts[1], 10, 8)
        b, _ := strconv.ParseInt(parts[2], 10, 8)
        fgcolor = color.RGBA{uint8(r), uint8(g), uint8(b), 255}
        break FGColorLoop
    }
}
```

I rewrote it (a first draft) in Go:

```
bgcolor, err := formColor(r, "bgcolor")
if err != nil {
    bgcolor = color.RGBA{0, 0, 0, 255}
}
fgcolor, err := formColor(r, "fgcolor")
if err != nil {
    fgcolor = color.RGBA{255, 255, 255, 255}
}
```

Where

```
var errFormColor = errors.New("invalid form color")

func formColor(r *http.Request, colorKey string) (color.RGBA, error) {
    var rgb [3]uint8

    value := r.Form[colorKey]
    if len(value) <= 0 {
        return color.RGBA{}, errFormColor
    }
    parts := strings.SplitN(value[0], ",", len(rgb)+1)
    if len(parts) != len(rgb) {
        return color.RGBA{}, errFormColor
    }
    for i, part := range parts {
        p, err := strconv.ParseUint(part, 10, 8)
        if err != nil {
            return color.RGBA{}, errFormColor
        }
        rgb[i] = uint8(p)
    }

    return color.RGBA{rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], 255}, nil
}
```

Comment: After fixing a few minor errors your code compiled, which surprised me because originally I had tried to delegate the same block of code to a function but it would not allow me to return the color. The compiler kept saying "color.RGBA is not a type." Eventually I gave up. I will try to duplicate that error later to see if I can figure out where I went wrong.

Thanks for your input!